# Convert Markdown to pdf with images on mac

Tags: macos, markdown, jupyter-notebook

This is driving me crazy.  I have a jupyter notebook with images and I'm trying to convert it to a pdf on my mac.  I've installed pandoc and macTex, but when I try to convert it to pdf the images disappear.  Also the formatting for my tables gets messed up.  I've tried saving it as a markdown and converting it, but I get the same problem.  If I convert to html the images disappear but the table formatting is correct.  I've also tried converting it in the terminal with nbconvert, but the images still disappeared.  And I tried converting the markdown file with rstudio, but still the images disappeared.  I've tried two versions of the code to reference images.  The versions are below, both display fine in the jupyter notebook but the first one throws an error and the second one the images disappear.  I've googled around, it seems to be a common issue but I'm not seeing a lot of solutions.  I really can't believe this is this difficult.  Any solution is greatly appreciated.

```
code with errors:
![Stars_Boxplot](Stars_Boxplot.PNG)

code disappears when rendered:
<img src="Stars_Boxplot.PNG">


Update Solution:

![Stars_Boxplot](/Users/Desktop///Project Research//Stars_Boxplot.PNG)
```

The issue was it had to be an absolute reference and I had a space in my file path.

Comment: Did you try `File -> Download As -> PDF via LaTeX (.pdf)`? As long as I don't use relative paths it works fine for me.

Comment: @JanTrienes  Thank you!  Yes the answer was absolute references and I had a space in my file path.